# HOD - Histogram of Oriented Depths

Tags: rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Are there any implementations of HOD in OpenCV, ROS or anywhere else?

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32116/hod---histogram-of-oriented-depths/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Grega,

have you found any implementation of HOD yet, or did your own one already?

Greetings,

Frie

---

Originally posted by [Frie159](https://answers.ros.org/users/3232/frie159/) with karma: 26 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-10-08**:
Haven't found any.